# How can I resolve below query

Tags: mysql, popsql

I’m practicing a code on pop sql, below is the code

```sql
CREATE TABLE student(
 student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 name VARCHAR(20),
 major VARCHAR(20),
);

DESCRIBE student;
```

It’s successful at first,

Then I drop table student, which deleted the table however when I click on the create table to run the code again as the tutor, it fails.I highlight complete query and run, it fails and I get the error message

Error:

> you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘)’ at line 6
> Error code: ER_PARSE_ERROR

I saw on a similar thread here where someone stated the second bracket is usually followed by a which space or so, tried that it didn’t work either

The video I followed on YouTube, the tutor did not have to highlight the entire code to run after he dropped the table for the entire query to be highlighted plus his ran successfully, not sure what I’m doing wrong? Also where can I find the manual that corresponds with the version of my sql?

Comment: `...major VARCHAR(20),...` remove that comma after the `)`

Comment: I says  "**near** ‘)’", which almost always should translate to "the part of the statement just before ')'".     Also  "It’s successful at first", but it is not, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/k_8oVb7C